# Do threads close once BroadcastReceiver.onCreate() finishes?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadcastReceiver and I need to do long operation there. This is my code:

```
public class clsMyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{  PowerManager oPowerManager;
   PowerManager.WakeLock oWakeLock;

   @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {  //Aviod the device to go to Sleep:
      oPowerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
      oWakeLock = oPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakelock");
      oWakeLock.acquire();

      new Thread()
      {  public void run()
         {  //......
            //Perform long operation here
            //......

            if(oWakeLock.isHeld())
              oWakeLock.release();
         }
      }.start();

   }
}
```

As far as I know this is not permitted because as soon as the onReceive finishes all the tasks created are killed. Is this right? Even if I use a WakeLock?
What is the best solution for this?
The "long operation" can last for about 2 minutes. I would like to avoid having another service for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create an AsyncTask and pass the `oWakeLock` to the constructor of AsyncTask.

```
 public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>{
    PowerManager.WakeLock oWakeLock;
    public MyTask(PowerManager.WakeLock oWakeLock){
    this.oWakeLock = oWakeLock;
    }
 // other methods of asyncktask below

}
```

Or same can be done with Threads, but AsyncTask are simpler to use.

```
class MyThread implements Runnable{


 PowerManager.WakeLock oWakeLock;
        public MyThread(PowerManager.WakeLock oWakeLock){
        this.oWakeLock = oWakeLock;
        }



 public void run(){
          // perform long running task
       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know this is not permitted because as soon as the onReceive finishes all the tasks created are killed. Is this right?

Not in the case of `Thread`s. If your `onReceive()` method gets fired, you execute everything in there but as you have a `Thread`, its execution occurs in background, so even if your `onReceive()` method finishes, your `Thread` keeps running until you either stop it or finishes itself after execution.

> Even if I use a WakeLock? What is the best solution for this? The "long operation" can last for about 2 minutes. I would like to avoid having another service for this. Thanks

You can do it the way you're doing, or declaring an `AsyncTask`. It's up to you to determine which solution fits better to your implementation, but both are valid.

Comment: This is what I read: **anything that requires asynchronous operation is not available, because you will need to return from the function to handle the asynchronous operation, but at that point the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active and thus the system is free to kill its process before the asynchronous operation completes.** (see it in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: I'm not really sure the repercusions of this. I understand that more than not allowing to do so, it can free the `BroadcastReceiver` at anytime in the middle of your Thread execution and it would unsafely end it. Have you tested it to see the behavior it takes?

Comment: A way would be using a `CountDownLatch(1)` synchronization, which works like a semaphore. Just before the end `}` of your `onReceive()` method, you'd call the `CountDownLatch.await()` method and your `Thread` would call the `.countDown()` method once it finishes. This way you're making sure your `onReceive()` method won't be freed until the `Thread` execution ends.

Comment: I have tested my code and works 90% of the times. But sometimes the thread gets killed. I also read this: **Once you return from onReceive, the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active, and its hosting process is only as important as any other application components that are running in it. This is important because if that process was only hosting the BroadcastReceiver (a common case for applications that the user has not recently interacted with), then upon returning from onReceive the system will consider its process to be empty and kill it so that resources are available for other processes.**

Comment: Hey nKn. Will not take to long your way? I mean, freezing in onReceive may take too long.

Comment: Yep, that's right, discard that idea. Can't you simply run that thread outside the `BroadcastReceiver` scope?